# Need help understanding the output of this code.

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

```
What is the output of running class Test?

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Circle9();
 }
}

public abstract class GeometricObject {
  protected GeometricObject() {
    System.out.print("A");
  }

  protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
    System.out.print("B");
  }
}

public class Circle9 extends GeometricObject {
  /** No-arg constructor */
  public Circle9() {
    this(1.0);
    System.out.print("C");
  }

  /** Construct circle with a specified radius */
  public Circle9(double radius) {
    this(radius, "white", false);
    System.out.print("D");
  }

  /** Construct a circle with specified radius, filled, and color */
  public Circle9(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(color, filled);
    System.out.print("E");
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me in some detail why the output of this code is BEDC? This is practice problem from a book I'm reading. I don't understand. Inherency has been a hard topic for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'explain me everything about this' is not a specific problem statement. Go through your code by hand or with a debugger, learn how polymorphism works, read your book more thoroughly and if you still have a very specific problem after that, post a new question. We are not here to explain entire topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright let's see.

First you call Circle9()

that starts the constructor:

```
/** No-arg constructor */
public Circle9() {
this(1.0);
System.out.print("C");
}
```

As you can see the constructor first calls `this(1.0)`

This means that another constructor is opened and *afterwards* we print "C"

Alright the next Constructor is:

```
public Circle9(double radius) {
this(radius, "white", false);
System.out.print("D");
}
```

The same thing happens, first another constructor is called with this, and then D is printed

The next called constructor is:

```
public Circle9(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
super(color, filled);
System.out.print("E");
}
```

This calls a super constructor. Since Circle9 extends GeometricObject it can use GeometricObject functions. So `super(color,filled)` calls

```
protected GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
System.out.print("B");
}
```

And prints B, then E from before, then D and lastly C

output should be BEDC

Comment: Cheers friend. That's all I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the rope:

`new Circle9();` →
 `new Circle9(1)` then `print("C")` →
 `new Circle9(1, white, false)` then `print("D")` then `print("C")` →
 `new GeometricObject(white, false)` then `print("E")` then `print("D")` then `print("C")` →
`print("B")`then `print("E")` then `print("D")` then `print("C")` →
"BEDC"